# Proof of Bethe-Bloch stopping power

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations

I want to prove the Bethe-Bloch stopping power formula but I don't know where to start. Any one can offer a book or paper?

Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethe_formula

Comment: What do you mean by "proof"? The formula works well in practice.

Comment: The National Institute of Standards and Technology calls formula "Bethe's stopping power formula".

On the other hand, in the 2008 Review of Particle Physics the formula was called "Bethe-Bloch equation", even though Bloch's expression did not appear in the formula. As of the most recent edition, this seems to have disappeared with the formula being called only the "Bethe formula"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a translation of the original paper by Bethe: [Bethe article](http://bookzz.org/book/1054577/d8570d)

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to work.